# WinApi: Access denied when creating disk

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, disk-partitioning

I'm running the following code with administrator privileges:

```
HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 
BOOL bResult = FALSE;                 // results flag
DWORD junk = 0;                     // discard results

hDevice = CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0",          // drive to open
    0,                // no access to the drive
    FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,             // default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
    0,                // file attributes
    NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
{
    std::cout << "invalid handle" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
std::cout << "handle " << hDevice << std::endl;

DRIVE_LAYOUT_INFORMATION_EX        drv_layout_info_ex;
CREATE_DISK        disk;
INT                n;

ZeroMemory(&disk, sizeof(CREATE_DISK));
disk.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
disk.Mbr.Signature = 0x7B060725;
bResult = ::DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK, &disk,
    sizeof(CREATE_DISK), NULL,
    0, &junk, NULL);
if (!bResult)
{
    std::cout << "IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK failed due to " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    return FALSE;
}
```

I get the output:

```
handle 00000048
IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK failed due to 5
```

Which is access denied. What is the problem?

Comment: PhysicalDrive0 sounds like the drive your Windows is running from. You can't just repartition that.

Comment: Let's look at this a different way. Windows told you you did not have access to do this. Why do you believe otherwise? Have you met all the requirements to open a handle to this drive?

Comment: How can I find the names of other drives? PhysicalDrive1 returns invalid handle, so do \Device\HarddiskVolume1 - \Device\HarddiskVolume4 which have been returned by FindNextVolumeW()

Comment: Can we stick to one question at a time, the one you asked

Comment: We're in the comment section, and it's a constructive follow-up

Comment: OK, we'll do it your way then.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942448

Comment: It didn't really work out doing it your way did it? It's probably too late to save this question now. How are you going to attract attention to it?

Comment: Did you figure this out? It looks like David was of no help. I'm facing the same issue.